# Send/receive data to external running application thru php

Tags: php, command-line

As I explain in the title, I have a running app in the background and would like to send commands to it as requested and get the results to the php pages in my local server.

If I run the app multiple times, my project loses its point so I can't use exec() or shell_exec() command.

Do you think it is possible to do? How/Why?

Thanks for the answers and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "inter-process communication" or IPC. Using that should give you plenty of input to get inspiration from. Also, just using what other programs use is a good approach. BTW: It is not at all clear to me what your setup looks like, especially when I'm trying to combine "running application" with "php pages in my local server"!